# Java iterators and generic type casts

Tags: java, generics, casting, iterator

I have a class VehicleFactory and a interface Car which extends the interface Vehicle

I work with a list of Cars within the VehicleFactory class but I only want it to return Vehicles

Specifically I want it to return a iterator of vehicles containing the instances present in the list of cars

```java
public class VehicleFactory() {

    private List<Car> cars;

    (...)

    public Iterator<Vehicles> vehicleIterator() {
       return ((List<Vehicles>)(List<? extends Vehicles>)this.cars).iterator();
    }

}
```

Is there a better, cleaner way to accomplish what is codded above without the use of wildcards?

Comment: Why not make cars a list of Vehicle, not Car?

Comment: Car has setter methods I don't want other classes to have access to.
Lets say Car allows me to have methods such as setColor(Color newColor) which I don't want other classes to be able to access using the iterator.

Comment: odd that the answer was deleted. it was correct.

Comment: I have no idea why he deleted it.
I wrote a comment on it about how the java documentation explicitly says you should avoid having wildcards as a return type.
Can you explain me why you think the other answer was better then the current implementation?

(the answer I am talking about had no cast and "<List ? extends Vehicles>" as the return type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do...

```
public Iterator<Vehicles> vehicleIterator() {
   return new ArrayList<Vehicles>(this.cars).iterator();
}
```

Or you might do...

```
public Iterator<Vehicles> vehicleIterator() {
   return Collections.<Vehicles>unmodifiableList(this.cars).iterator();
}
```

Or you might do...

```
public Iterator<Vehicles> vehicleIterator() {
   return new Iterator<Vehicles>() {
       Iterator<Car> it = this.cars.iterator();
       public boolean hasNext() { return it.hasNext(); }
       public Vehicles   next() { return it.next();    }
       public void     remove() {        it.remove();  }
   };
}
```

Or you might do what you are doing now, which is *probably* OK unless you cast the `Iterator` to a `ListIterator` and put stuff in it with `add` or `set`.